# Could someone tell me why my actionListener for-loop is not working?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, actionlistener

I have a program that takes an input file, pulls a color word + hexadecimal value from it (for exaple Red 0xFF0000).  I had my code working perfectly except I tried to replace my 2 arrayLists with a HashMap...  That is where things took a wrong turn.  I have my code back to what I believe it was before except now it is NOT changing colors when the radio buttons are pushed. Anyone want to take a peek?

```
public HashMapTests() {
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(5,4));
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        for (int i = 0; i < colorCollection.size(); i++) {
            jrbColor[i] = new JRadioButton(colorCollection.get(i));
            jrbColor[i].setText(colorCollection.get(i));
            group.add(jrbColor[i]); 
            p1.add(jrbColor[i]);
            }
        for(int i = 0; i < colorCollection.size(); i++){
            jrbColor[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    for (int j = 0; j < colorCollection.size(); j++){
                        String hexColor = hexCollection.get(j);
                        if(hexCollection.get(j).equals(((JRadioButton)e.getSource()).getText())){
                            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode(hexColor));

                            repaint();
                        }
                    }                   
            }
        }); 
        }
        add(p1);
            }
```

Comment: Time to do a little debugging, me-thinks.

Comment: How your input files do look?

Comment: @LeosLiterak: they most likely have two columns of Strings -- a color name followed by a String representation of a color int hex String. i.e., `Red 0xffff0000`. This is my guess anyway.

Comment: Where is your HashMap? I see two ArrayLists.

Comment: @LeosLiterak I could not get the HashMap to function the way I had hoped so I scrapped it and went back to two arrays.  I was going to keep working on the HashMap.  And yes my input looks like:
    `Gray 0x707070
    Purple 0x990099
    Orange 0xFF6600
    LightBlue 0x6666FF`

Comment: @ch4dr0x see my answear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First investigation:

```
while (colorCollection.size() < 10)
```

shall be replaced with

```
if (colorCollection.size() < 10)
```

Second observation:

```
jrbColor[i] = new JRadioButton(colorCollection.get(i));
jrbColor[i].setText(colorCollection.get(i));
```

The second line is useless, see constructor's javadoc.

Third:

The second loop where you attach the listener is useless, you can put this code to the first loop where you create a button.

Finally:

```
if (hexCollection.get(j).equals(((JRadioButton) e.getSource()).getText())) {
```

You compare here content of hexCollection with radio button text, but the button has label from colorCollection. I cannot look to your file but I think that this will be the problem.

Map Solution:

Initialization

```
String name = fileInput.next();
String hexValue = fileInput.next();
colors.put(name, hexValue);
```

Buttons

```
    int i = 0;
    for (String s : colors.keySet()) {
        jrbColor[i] = new JRadioButton(s);
        group.add(jrbColor[i]);
        p1.add(jrbColor[i]);
        jrbColor[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String hexColor = colors.get(((JRadioButton) e.getSource()).getText());
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode(hexColor));
        }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You absolutely nailed it with the reason the radio buttons were not working.  UGH!  Now I can go back trying to get a hashmap working on this bad boy.

Comment: Sorry, I just posted hashmap solution :-)

Comment: The only part I couldn't figure out earlier was how to spawn the buttons using the HashMap.
`for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
             jrbColor[i] = new JRadioButton(colors.get(i));
             group.add(jrbColor[i]); 
             p1.add(jrbColor[i]);
                    }
`
is just not spawning them.  Same spot I got stuck earlier :(

Comment: and now is it more clear? See Map interface, javadoc is mighty tool

Comment: Thank you so much, Leos.  I really appreciate that.  Now that I see it in front of me, it absolute makes more sense.

Comment: programming is easy, just go on :-)